# Foundry - how to console log a uint256 as a hex?

Tags: foundry

I'm using foundry to debug some smart contracts, and I'm trying to figure out how to log out a `uint256` and view it as hex.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to convert it to a `bytes32` and log it as such. Example:

```js
import {console} from "forge-std/Console.sol";
// some code here
uint256 myNumber = 12345;
console.logBytes32(bytes32(myNumber));
```